# Executable crashing(SEGV_MAPERR) on access POSIX Semaphore on target machine

Tags: c++, linux, posix, semaphore

I have made a executable which tries to access and get the state or change the state of an existing named POSIX semaphore created by the process on the target machine(Ubuntu 16.04) running at niceness level:-19.
My program, I have made in C++ on Ubuntu 16.04. On accessing the semaphore on the target machine by program compiled by the target machine, the semaphore is being accessed and changed properly. But when accessed by my machine's compiled executable, it gives SEGV_MAPERR segmentation fault.
On testing with another semaphore locking/unlocking program on my machine, the program works.I am keeping the permissions as 777 and flags as O_CREAT | O_EXCL on programs on both programs on both machines.

[Erro on running on target machine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghc0R.png)

[Backtrace by GDB on Target machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASuvc.png)

I am using semaphore.h library on both the machines.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I just had to remove the O_EXCL flag and I also had to run my application as root.